# Install a specific release of bioconductor package

Tags: r, installation, package, bioconductor

I had a `bioconductor` package version 1.2.14, and I've just updated it to version 1.4.2 and unfortunately I get different results.

I want to make sure this is because of the package update. Is there a way to revert to the old version, or alternatively to remove the current version and specify installation of the old one?

Alternatively, I can see the branches on GitHub and I wonder whether they correspond to the different version from Bioconductor. 
So, can I install from a GitHub branch release?

Comment: What's the package? Did you 'just update it' using Bioconductor's `biocLite()` command? It will help determine the correct solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step1** In Object Browser (of Revo R Ent), right-click the `bioconductor` package under "Packages Loaded", and then click Unload Package.

**Step2** In Object Browser (of Revo R Ent), right-click the `bioconductor` package under "Packages Installed", and then click Unload Package.

**Step3** Close the R's GUI (in my example:Revo R Ent).

**Step4** (For Revo R Ent users) Delete the .xml file:

```
C:\Users\User\Documents\Revolution\32_7.3\PackageXMLs\bioconductor.xml
```

The file bioconductor.xml (related with v1.4.2) has the duty of the functions of `bioconductor 1.4.2` to be processed in R's GUI.

**Step5** Get your library location via:

```
.libPaths()    
[1] "C:/Revolution/R-Enterprise-7.3/R-3.1.1/library"
```

**Step6** Delete the folder of `bioconductor` package from Windows Explorer in the library location.
(Now, you got rid of `bioconductor` 1.4.2)

**Step7** Open Revo R Enterprise. Install `bioconductor` package version 1.2.14:
Install - Install Packages from Local Zip Files...- Select .zip of `bioconductor` 1.2.14 - OK.

Now, `bioconductor` folder (related with 1.2.14) is listed in your library location.

**Step8** `library(bioconductor) # Now, bioconductor v. 1.2.14 works in your R's GUI.`

(For Revo R Ent users) The new file `bioconductor.xml` (related with v1.2.14) are created in `C:\Users\User\Documents\Revolution\32_7.3\PackageXMLs`

Even if you close Revo R Ent, this .xml file sustains in the PackageXMLs folder to act as bufferly.

Though I gave the solution for "Revolution R Enterprise" GUI for R, the solution mechanism is the same for other R's GUIs.