# In continuation to previously asked "Unable to work with R-extension in NetLogo"

Tags: r, netlogo, rjava

After changing all the needed environment varaibles ( Control Panel/ System/Advanced system settings/Environment Variables) in windows 8, when I am installing rJava Package I get errors as below

[image]

I tried in MsDOS immediately after changing environment variables, 
        first step >R                        "it was successful" 
        second     >install.packages("rJava") "got error in this step"
     then I tried  >install.packages("rJava",  repos="https://cran.rstudio.com/") "but again I did not succeeded"

I am tired of trying all this, I referred many links already but all in vain. Yes, I am using Proxy also. Please help any one.

Comment: 1) It seems a download problem first. So do this: Download rJava_0.9-8.zip from CRAN (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rJava/index.html). Then, in Revolution R Enterprise; Packages - "Install Packages From local Zip Files..." - Choose rJava_0.9-8.zip - OK.

Answer (score 1):

**1)** It seems a download problem first. So do this:
Download rJava_0.9-8.zip from CRAN (cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rJava/index.html). Then, in Revolution R Enterprise; Packages - "Install Packages From local Zip Files..." - Choose rJava_0.9-8.zip - OK. If the problem is solved then OK.

If the problem persists, try the following Step.

**2)** Look at DESCRIPTION file in rJava (in library location):

```
Package: rJava
Version: 0.9-8
....
Depends: R (>= 2.5.0), methods
....
NeedsCompilation: yes
```

Your R version may be incompatible. Look at the warning: "rJava is not available for R3.3.0" in your screenshot. So do this:
Unzip file rJava_0.9-8.zip to R's working directory; the folder rJava is created there. Change R version accordingly (you may introduce lower version number in Depends section). Save the changed DESCRIPTION file. Apply classical procedure:

```
library(roxygen2) # install this package first if not done yet
library(devtools) # install this package first if not done yet
library(digest) # install this package first if not done yet
```

Note: Since rJava folder is created manually, no `package.skeleton` is needed at this stage.

```
roxygenize("rJava")
build("rJava")
install("rJava")
```

The above technique must solve the problem (It solved previously many R version problems!). 
Analyze this one also:
[Install a specific release of bioconductor package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37503884/install-a-specific-release-of-bioconductor-package/37504308#37504308) (where the solution I wrote solved the problem of the questioner).
If you still have problems, trigger the following:

```
sessionInfo(); getwd(); .libPaths()
```

and print the output in your question so that we can analyze if you have any machine-spesific or installation-spesific problems.